# Agregate data from multiple rows in one row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL server DB for credit card processing system with 5 Tables

MerchantContract

```
PaymentKey   NVARCHAR(50)
ProcessingID INT
```

DealTrace

```
Status       NVARCHAR(250)
Tag          NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

DealSummmary

```
RefNumber    NVARCHAR(100)
DealAuthCode NVARCHAR(100)
```

Processing

```
Name         NVARCHAR(50)
```

And Deal with whole bunch of fields of which the most important one are

```
OriginalOrderId  NVARCHAR(50)
MerchantContract INT
Amount           INT
```

Currently I'm querying these tables with such query:

```
SELECT  d.id, 
        d.date, 
        d.ip, 
        d.panmask, 
        d.merchantorderid, 
        d.amount, 
        d.cardholder, 
        d.bankhumanname, 
        d.cardtypeid, 
        d.bankcountrycode, 
        d.usercountrycode, 
        mc.paymentkey as merchantname, 
        dt.status, 
        d.merchantcontract, 
        dt.tag, 
        d.originalorderid, 
        ds.refnumber, 
        ds.dealauthcode, 
        mc.processingid, 
        pc.Name as processing, 
        d.customparams 
FROM Deal as d 
LEFT JOIN MerchantContract as mc ON mc.Id = d.MerchantContract 
LEFT JOIN DealTrace as dt ON d.Id = dt.DealId 
AND dt.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM DealTrace WITH (nolock) WHERE DealId = d.id) 
LEFT JOIN DealSummary ds ON d.Id = ds.DealId 
AND ds.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM DealSummary WITH (nolock) WHERE DealId = d.id) 
LEFT JOIN Processing pc on mc.ProcessingId = pc.id WHERE (d.MerchantContract IN ('13')) 
ORDER BY ID desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

However for each `MerchantContract` there might be several rows with `OriginalOrderId` but different values in other columns. For example

```
MerchantContract|OriginalOrderID|Status|Amount|...
3|13_Qrta|charge|101|...
3|13_Qrta|refund|94|...
4|15_Utq1|charge|56|...
```

I would like for each unique pair of `MercahntContract` `OriginalOrderId` aggregate data in one row, so above resuklt would look like

```
MerchantContract|OriginalOrderID|Status|Amount|...
3|13_Qrta|charge,refund|101,94|...
4|15_Utq1|charge|56|...
```

I was looking around but unfortunately couldn't find solution. I was trying to modify first FROM to

```
SELECT ...
(SELECT * FROM Deal d1 WHERE d1.Id=(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Deal d2 "+
    "WHERE d2.OriginalOrderId=d1.OriginalOrderId)) d 
LEFT JOIN ...
```

But it didn't give the required result. Would really appreciate if anybody could give any hints as to how go about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [For XML Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623593/what-is-the-meaning-of-select-for-xml-path-1-1)..

```
select 
Merchant_contract,
OriginalOrderid,
Stuff(
(Select ','+ status from yourtable t2 where t2.Merchant_contract=t1.Merchant_contract
and 
t2.orderid=t1.orderid
For Xml Path(''))
,1,2,'') as status
---do similarly for other columns
from 
yourtable t1
group by 
Merchant_contract,
OriginalOrderid
```